# Trouble in changing the hive metadata db from derby to RDS mysql instance in aws

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, amazon-rds

I followed the following steps to change my default metastore db for hive to rds MySQL instance.

1)Create a MySQL instance in rds.Change the security groups as per my EC2 instance.

2)Install hive in EC2 linux instance

3)Change the hive-env.xml to include hadoop path

3)then change the hive-site.xml as follows(attached the screen shot).
Then when i am creating a table from hive shell,no error is coming but i can't see my table schema in MySQL instance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN6zH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your EC2 instance is still using the default hive metastore, thats why you are not able to see the tables in mysql instance.